# How to change the color of markers on the scroll bar?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt

In Zend Studio (or Eclipse PDT) when you select a property/method the scroll bar shows markers of where else in the source file it's referenced.

I have a problem seeing the those markers. They are to close to the same color as the scroll bar and when my eyes are tired it's really hard to see.

Is there a way to change the colors of these markers to something different (like bright green).

Even in the attached sample image they are hard to see. So I circled them in red.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mathew - this might be better asked on SuperUser, as it's not directly a programming question. Well asked though, good screenshot!

Comment: I have an account at SuperUser. Maybe an admin can move this. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences, and at the top, search for: `Annotations`.

I believe, the ones you're looking for will be under General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations.

Comment: thanks! That did the trick. I would never have figured that out.